# How to integrate Data Hub (POIs, Styles) with Android App using Here Maps SDK

Tags: java, maps, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I'm currently using (Here maps freemium plan), integrated Here maps Android SDK (Premium Edition -version 3.18) with Android studio project.

Also created a Data Hub project at (https://studio.here.com/) with a layer that contains POIs data with customized points style.

What I'm trying to do is, integrating data from Data Hub with my Android project, so customized POIs will be visible on the map once it's loaded. I do know that adding a `MapContainer` can work as a map layer, then can hold multiple `MapMarker` objects, but I don't think this would be a wise move when working with **huge amount** of POIs and other Data.


So, it there a method to build a connection between Data Hub and Android project, to automatically sync data and styles?

Is this because of the freemium plan?

And if it's a plan limitation, where's the documentation for building such connection?

Since, the only thing I'm receiving once publishing Data Hub project is a viewer link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XYZ API](https://www.here.xyz/api/) to request your data on HERE Data Hub, download per tile or full data set or even search with location or attributes. You need to defile the caller in your app to call XYZ API, then convert them to MapObject and render them on the map.

Comment: Then the only way to add POIs is by sending API request then create native MapObjects on-top of the map in my Android project. And I can't create a connection between the map on Android and my Data hub data to automatically create ViewObject of type PROXY_OBJECT once the map is loaded. Is that true? 
Thanks for your response!

Comment: If your data is point style, you can use MapMarker, instead of Proxy Object. HERE Data Hub provides API to load it by tile or bounding box. But you need to handle the logic of de-duplicating while panning and zooming the map.